# Изменение таблицы и запись в БД

Tags: jquery, php, html

Добрый день.
Есть таблица со значениями. Хочется сделать:

1. Кнопку редактирования. Нажимаешь - в строке появляются edit-ы и можно вносить изменения и потом их сохранить (как-то сослаться на id элемента).
2. Мгновенное редактирование таблицы и занесение аяксом в базу данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примеры.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как сделано это у меня [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9rqv4on/4/)

Чтобы изменения записывались в базу, в blur()(в 15 строку) добавьте ajax-запрос со ссылкой на php, который будет работать с БД.
В php-файле должно быть что-то такое

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$target = $_GET['target'];
$entry = $_GET['entry'];
$query = "UPDATE `tracks` SET `$target` = '$entry' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$result = $mysql_connect->query($query);
```

Comment: @Михаил Налётов, а почему бы просто не установить для редактируемых элементов атрибут **contenteditable**?

Comment: @Deonis спасибо за информацию, я не знал о подобном атрибуте. Ради саморазвития - а как в таком случае отправлять данные? Следить за фокусом на элементе?

Comment: @Михаил Налётов, по поводу завершения редактирования - это уже на вкус ТС. Кстати, id элемента, на мой взгляд, лучше бы прописать в атрибут **data-*** (*всё-таки ближе к сути*)

Answer (score 0):

Со слов не очень понятно, в чем дело.

1. Давай ячейкам таблицы соответствующие idшники. Определи событие изменения и по нему выполняй действия из п.2.
2. аякс -> пхп скрипт -> апдейт/инсерт.